# Kafka Stream with Java: Send TO multiple topics

Tags: java, list, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to output my messages using Kafka Streams using Java to multiple topics with something like:

```
myStream.to(
    (key, message, recordContext) -> {
         return getMessageTargetTopics(message);
    },
    Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde)
);
```

The issue is that `getMessageTargetTopics` returns a list of topics and the method `to` doesn't accept lists...

I saw there is already an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3805) targeting this, but I was wondering if there was any possible solution in the meanwhile. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the simple solution does not seem to work: You should have a list of all topics that might be returned by the getMessageTargetTopics.

**Solution 1** *(Streams DSL, but not so "clean")*: Use branches to implement that logic and select the topic(s).

**Solution 2** *(IHMO much cleaner)*: Add all the topics as sinks and build a custom processor that forwards to the corresponding sink node(s) - something like context.forward(key, value, To.child("topic")) looping over the Topic-List should do it.

Comment: I don't think that using `branch()` is "less clean". Overall, this answer compared to all others, seems to provide the best approach.

Comment: Can Streams DSL and custom Processor mix and match?   For example can we add Sink to existing StreamsBuilder?  I know we can have a TransformerSupplier, but don't know where to declare "To" name for context.forward(key, value, TO)

Comment: Turns out you can do Topology top = builder.build(); followed by top.addSink(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KStream:flatMapValues(...)` to calculate topics for each value. Topic name should be wrapped with value and later unwrapped.

**Notice:**
There is drawback of such approach - your message's value will contain topic name, so application, that uses those messages has extract *business value*

Sample code will look like follow:

```
myStream.flatMapValues(value -> getMessageTargetTopicsWrappedWithValue(value))
    .to((key, value, recordContext) -> value.getTopicName, 
        Produced.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
```

Comment: This was actually the first approach I took, the thing is then in the to(...) you will be sending the wrapped value and not the original one...